# Depending on how many vespene geysers I spot at minutes 2 - 5 - 7, which units/upgrades can I exclude?

Tags: starcraft-2, sc2-build-order

I was wondering, assuming proper scouting is possible and I can spot how many geysers (from 0 to 4) a player has taken and is mining from, which upgrades and units I can exclude **for each race** at **minutes 2, 5, 7**?

Even partial answers are welcome (i.e. only against terran), also if you think the timings don't make sense please propose better reference timings. I am limiting the question to minute 7 because after that and 4 geysers are up you can expect pretty much anything.

GLHF!

Comment: It is important to note that when you are scouting, you can click on the geyser to see how much gas it has and figure out how long they have been harvesting.

Answer (score 2):

2 minutes:
   All units
I say this because, at least in the matches I have played and watched no one gets a geyser by the two minute mark.  All races are typically pumping workers.

5 minutes:
   Terran:
     Thor
     Siege mode
     Drop ship
     Battlecruiser
     +2 anything
     +1 mech weapon/armor

7 minutes:
    Terran:
       Thor
       Battlecruiser
       +3 anything
       +2 mech weapon/armor